# Xamarin.Forms Embedded Camera in Page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build an application similar to apps such as Mathpix or Photomath which has a live camera feed and a resize-able box in the middle to tell the camera exactly where to scan. I am wondering how I can replicate this behavior in Xamarin.Forms.

[Resizeable Camera Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1mvW.jpg)

Click the link to view the image of the screen I am attempting to replicate. When a user taps on the screen the cropped image is highlighted and then that input is processed. All I need to do is create a replica UI without the backend processing.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you'll need to do this in each platform project.  Both Android and iOS support the concept of camera overlays which allows you to layer custom UI over the camera view